# assembly maximum value from input

Tags: assembly, x86

Simple assembly program to spit out the greater of two user input numbers. I am having trouble getting the output correct. Example if I entered 45 and 55, the maximum value would be 55, however when I try the reverse 55 and 45 (the answer should still be 55) I get 45. It would appear that this program only ever outputs the second value entered and stored at EAX. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT

INCLUDE io.h

.STACK 4096

.DATA
value1 DWORD ?
value2 DWORD ?

prompt1 BYTE "Enter the first number", 0
prompt2 BYTE "Enter the second number", 0
string BYTE 40 DUP (?)

resultLbl BYTE  "The maximum value you entered was:", 0

.CODE

_MainProc PROC      
input prompt1, string, 40       ;get user input value1
atod string                     ;convert input (ASCII) to integer
mov ebx, eax

input prompt2, string, 40   ; repeat for value2
atod string
mov value2, eax

cmp eax, ebx                ;compare user inputs

jg greater_than     ;jump conditional if value 1 is greater then value 2

    greater_than:   ;condition if greater than ouput
        dtoa value1, eax                    ;decimal to ASC for output of 
integer value stored at ebx
        output  resultLbl, value1           ;output value 1
            jmp exit                    

    less_than:  ;condition if less than ouput
        dtoa value1, eax
        output  resultLbl, value2           ;else output value 2    
            jmp exit

    exit:   ;quit jump              ;end if/else conditional

    mov eax, 0          ;clear memory
    mov ebx, 0
    ret
_MainProc ENDP
END
```

Comment: Debug it. Most likely ebx gets overwritten in the function calls. Store it in memory, not a register

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen No registers are affected by `input`, according to the following link: http://flylib.com/books/en/2.265.1.27/1/

Quoting from the link:
The input macro changes only memory at the specified destination. It does not change any register contents, including the flag register.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the order of instructions. Even if operand 1 is less than operand 2, the only difference it makes is that `jg greater_than` shall not result in explicit jump to `greater_than` label. However, the very next set of instructions is to print operand 1, that is, the control of execution will go "inside" `greater_than` label. Why? That's because the next instruction `dtoa value1, eax` is exactly after `jg greater_than`. So, do you see the problem now? You aren't preventing the printing of operand 1 if operand 1 is less than operand 2. All your code is doing is to ensure that your program prints `value1` for sure if operand 1 > operand 2.

Your code is the equivalent to the following C code:

```
if (op1>op2)goto gt;
gt: 
printf("%d",op1);
exit(0);

lt:
printf("%d",op2);
exit(0);
```

While your intention was to do the following:

```
if(op1>op2){
 printf("%d",op1);
 exit(0);
}

printf("%d",op2);
exit(0);
```

To solve this you'll have to change the order of instructions, like this:

```
jg greater_than     ;jump conditional if value 1 is greater then value 2

    less_than:  ;condition if less than ouput
        dtoa value1, ebx
        output  resultLbl, value1           ;else output value 2    
            jmp exit

    greater_than:   ;condition if greater than ouput
        dtoa value1, eax                    ;decimal to ASC for output of integer value stored at eax
        output  resultLbl, value1           ;output value 1
            jmp exit
```

The above code ensures that code inside `less_than` label is prevented from being executed when operand 1 > operand 2, by making an explicit jump to `greater_than` label. When operand 1 <= operand 2, no explicit jump is made and next instruction in the sequence is executed. In this case, the instrcutions inside `less_than` are executed when operand 1 <= operand 2.

**In a nutshell**, conditional jumps result in a jump only if the condition is satisfied, else the next instruction in the sequence is executed. It's your responsibility to put your instructions in the correct order. They are unlike high level conditional constructs like if...else.

**Update:** Please note that only `value1` is being used in my entire solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have had some experience in C++ so the logic I understood, it was the implementation in assembly that seems to trip me up.

Comment: how could I incorporate this to check 3 numbers?

Answer (score 1):

As said Mayank Verma if you jump with "jg greater_than" immediately after this instruction, even when EAX <= EBX you execute the same instructions that should be executed for the EAX>EBX condition, you never execute jump to less_than. The label "less_than" can be removed. You should write:

```
    CMP EAX,EBX
     JG greater_than

;less_than
   dtoa value1, eax
 output resultLbl, value2
    jmp exit

greater_than:
integer value stored at ebx
 output resultLbl, value1

exit:
```

But I've a new solution. That is a optimized MAX(A,B) function:

```
;  INPUT: EAX, EBX
; OUTPUT: EAX <- The maximum value between EAX, EBX

   CMP EAX,EBX
 CMOVL EAX,EBX
```

Answer (score -1):

3 values entered. Does this look like it would work?

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT

INCLUDE io.h

.STACK 4096

.DATA
value1 DWORD ?
value2 DWORD ?
value3 DWORD ?

titleLbl BYTE   "MAXIMUM NUMBERS",0
formula BYTE "Taking any THREE random user input numbers, this program can 
determine which of those numbers is greater.",0

prompt1 BYTE "Enter the first number",0
prompt2 BYTE "Enter the second number",0
prompt3 BYTE "Enter the third number",0
string BYTE 40 DUP (?)

resultLbl BYTE  "The maximum value you entered was:", 0
max_value BYTE 11 DUP (?), 0

.CODE

_MainProc PROC  
output titleLbl, formula

input prompt1, string, 40       ;get user input value1
atod string                     ;convert input (ASCII) to integer
mov ebx, eax

input prompt2, string, 40   ; repeat for value2
atod string
mov ecx, eax

input prompt3, string, 40   ; repeat for value2
atod string
mov value3, eax

cmp ebx, ecx                ;compare user inputs

jg greater_than     ;jump conditional if value 2 is greater then value 3

less_than:  ;condition if less than ouput
    cmp eax, ecx

    jg greater_than_again   ;jump conditional if 2 is greater than 1

    less_than_again: 
        dtoa max_value, ecx
        output  resultLbl, max_value          ;else output value 2    
        jmp exit

    greater_than_again:
    dtoa max_value, eax                    ;decimal to ASC for output of 
 integer value stored at eax
    output  resultLbl, max_value           ;output value 1
        jmp exit

greater_than:   ;condition if greater than ouput
    cmp eax, ebx

    jg greater_than_again   ;jump conditional if 2 is greater than 1

    less_than_again2: 
        dtoa max_value, ebx
        output  resultLbl, max_value          ;else output value 2    
        jmp exit

    greater_than_again2:
    dtoa max_value, eax                    ;decimal to ASC for output of 
 integer value stored at eax
    output  resultLbl, max_value           ;output value 1
        jmp exit

    exit:   ;quit jump              ;end if/else conditional

    mov eax, 0          ;clear memory
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, 0
    ret
 _MainProc ENDP
 END
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a correct answer to the question?  You posted it as an answer.

Comment: I thought it might have been a new question, since you said "Does this look like it would work?".  That's not how you usually start an answer.  If you have tested this and it works, that's fine.

Comment: Yes I know, I used the wrong link to add a comment. I will correct next time. Thanks for the help.